# How to using `regexp` to remove all the character not in chinese and english

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

There is `ori_string` ，how to using `regexp` to remove all the character not in chinese and english? Thanks!

```
ori_string<-"没a w t _ 中/国.sz"
```

the wished result  is

```
  "没awt中国sz"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have coded it in python, as you didn't specify anything. The idea is here.

```
def remove_non_english_chinese(text):
    # Use a regex pattern to match any character that is not a letter or number
    pattern = r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\u4e00-\u9fff]'

    # Replace all non-English and non-Chinese characters with an empty string
    return re.sub(pattern, '', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to remove punctuation and spaces:

```
> regex <- '[[:punct:][:space:]]+'
> gsub(regex, '', ori_string)
[1] "没awt中国sz"
```